# Pass first item of subscribed data to service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

I am developing angular application where I need apply following mechanism:

My view has 2 parts (list of items and detail if selected item). User can click on some item, and next service fetch additional data for that item and show them in detail view. Also I want select first item automatically on start if is available.

Here is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

  private url: string;
  private itemSource = new BehaviorSubject<Item>(null);
  selectedItem = this.itemSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/item';
  }

  getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    let observable = this.http.get<Item[]>(this.url)
      .map(items => items.map(item => {
        return new Item(item);
      }));
    return observable;
  }

  selectItem(item: Item) {
    return this.http.get<Item>(this.url + '/' + item.id)
      .map(item => new Item(item))
      .subscribe(t => this.itemSource.next(t));
  }
}
```

in detail component I am subscribing selected item like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.selectedItem.subscribe(item => this.selectedItem = item);
  }
```

and following code is from my component where I displayed list of items. I also want set selected item after data are subscribed but my code isn't works. I am iterating items[] property in html template and data are showed, but when I access to this array after I subscribed data I got undefined. Can you please fix my code? Thanks!

```
  public items = [];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItems()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.items = data,
        err => console.log(err),
        function () {
          console.log('selected data', this.items); // this prints undefined
          if (this.items && this.items.length) {
            this.itemService.selectedItem(this.items[0])
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using an arrow function for the `complete` callback in your call to `subscribe`. As you see, you are using arrow functions for `next` and `error`.

When you define a new function with `function(...) {...}` you're creating a new context, and so the `this` keyword changes its meaning. The difference between arrow function and normal functions (besides being more elegant, in my opinion), is that arrow functions do not define a new context for `this`, and so the meaning of that keyword is the same as in the context they are defined. So, in your `next` and `error` callbacks, `this` is your component, but in your call to `complete`, `this` is, most surely, a reference to `window`, which does not have an `items` property, hence the `undefined`.

Change your code to:

```
public items = [];

constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.itemService.getItems()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.items = data,
    err => console.log(err),
    () => {
      console.log('selected data', this.items); // this prints undefined
      if (this.items && this.items.length) {
        this.itemService.selectedItem(this.items[0])
      }
    });
}
```

I imagine you used the `function` keyword there because that function had not arguments, but you can express that with the syntax `() => expression`, or `() => {...}`

`data => this.items = data`, after all, is a simpler and more elegant way of writing

```
(data) => { return this.items = data; }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation!